# Find jQuery script through IE11

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

Using `inspect element` through IE11, I'm having an issue trying to get Javascript code through the web browser. **Using Firefox, it's plain & simple:**

[image]

`F12 (inspect element)  >  Pick an element from the page tool  >  Click ev at the end of HTML code  >  Click jQuery for function to show (as shown in red outlined box)`

**Internet Explorer 11:**

[image]

I cannot understand the code and it's muddled up. I am using an example event, it's jQuery that injects onto the website using a button. The reason I need it through internet explorer is the certain event I am looking for is compatible with and only IE11 so I physically can't view/find it in Firefox.

Is there a better way of viewing jQuery through Internet Explorer 11? Can I download an alternative developer tools?

Comment: How about using a later version than 1.4.4 ?

Comment: @mplungjan I don't have control over the javascript code, it's off another website

Comment: There are no any options available in IE developer tools to modify or change the UI of developer tools and display the JQuery code in separate window like Firefox. I will try to provide feedback about this request to Microsoft developers. So they can consider it for future request for developer tools for IE and MS Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Found a website that cleans up the format.

https://beautifier.io/

It isn't perfect but you can work with it